# Write a class in PHP Symfony 4.4 using the design pattern Factory Method to instantiate Service classes

Tags: php, symfony, design-patterns

Using Symfony 4.4 with autowiring activated, I want to instantiate a class using the design-pattern FactoryMethod.

The class instantiated is a service with autowired arguments passed into the constructor.

It work well if the constructor is the same for each type of class to instantiate inside the factory method.

But, each service to instantiate has to autowire some specific service in order to work.

I found that we could use the "setter dependency injection". Articles describing it:

- https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/logger-trait
- https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection

I tried to implement the setter dependency injection but the code inside is never executed.

Considering the articles, we should enter the setters with the PHPDoc "@required" immediately after the __construct method has been called (from what I understood).

It doesn't work with my code (see below).

Is my implementation correct?

Is there a better way of doing it?

My code looks like:

```
// Controller
/**
 *@Route("/my_action/{param}")
 */
public function my_action (ThingManagerFactory $thingManagerFactory, $param)
{
    $thingManager = $thingManagerFactory->get($param);
    $thingManager->doSomething();
}


// ThingManagerFactory

class ThingManagerFactory
{
    private $firstManager;
    private $secondManager;
    private $thirdManager;

    public function __construct(FirstManager $firstManager, SecondManager $secondManager, ThirdManager $thirdManager)
    {
        $this->firstManager = $firstManager;
        $this->secondManager = $secondManager;
        $this->thirdManager = $thirdManager;
    }

    public function get($param): ThingManagerInterface
    {
        if($param == 1) {
            return new Thing1Manager(
                $this->firstManager,
                $this->secondManager,
                $this->thirdManager,
            );
        } elseif($param == 2) {
            return new Thing2Manager(
                $this->firstManager,
                $this->secondManager,
                $this->thirdManager,
            );
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("...");
    }
}


// ThingManagerInterface
interface ThingManagerInterface
{
    public function __construct(
            $this->firstManager,
            $this->secondManager,
            $this->thirdManager,
        );
    public function doSomething();
}


// Thing1Manager
class Thing1Manager implements ThingManagerInterface
{
    (...)
    private $spec1Manager;

    public function __construct(
            $this->firstManager,
            $this->secondManager,
            $this->thirdManager,
        )
    {
        (...)
    }

    /**
     * @required
     */
    public function setSpecificManager(Spec1Manager $spec1Manager)
    {
        // this code is never called
        $this->spec1Manager = $spec1Manager;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // we pass here before going into setSpecificManager
        (...)
    }
}


// Thing2Manager class
// is similar to Thing1Manager with multiple other specific managers.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The '@required' parameter works in conjunction with the Symfony container.  The new operator knows nothing about it.  Your instructor might be talking about [service locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html). But you really need to ask him/her/other for more details.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to do exactly what it is said here: [autowiring other methods](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-other-methods-e-g-setters).

Comment: Yes but autowire only works within the Symfony service container.  return new Thing1Manager() is not going to call Thing1Manager::setSpecificManager automatically.  With a service locator (which is basically a Symfony container) you would have return $serviceLocator->get($param) which would take care of injecting all the dependencies.

Comment: I don't understand where I have to define the service locator. Do I have to define it in each ThingXManager with the specific Services each one need? Or else in the controller and forget about writing the FactoryMethod class?
Where should I place the "return $serviceLocator->get($param)"?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: When trying to add the service locator inside Thing1Manager with:
    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return [
            'App\Manager\Spec1Manager' => Spec1Manager::class
        ];
    }
I get the following error:
The "App\Manager\Spec1Manager" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

Comment: After a few tries, I finally found the right solution for my case. Thank you @Cerad for your help. The solution is to use a service locator as you suggested, then I was able to make the setter injection work and I realized that it was useless in my case. I will post the final structure as a reply today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the design-pattern Factory Method with Symfony, use the Service Locator to provide autowire outside a Controller.
Refactor the code to the following:

```
// Controller
/**
 *@Route("/my_action/{param}")
 */
public function my_action (ThingManagerFactory $thingManagerFactory, $param)
{
    $thingManager = $thingManagerFactory->get($param);
    $thingManager->doSomething();
}


// ThingManagerFactory
use App\Locator\ThingLocator;
class ThingManagerFactory
{
    private $locator;

    public function __construct(ThingLocator $locator)
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function get($param): ThingManagerInterface
    {
        if($param == 1) {
            return $this->locator->get(Thing1Manager::class);
        } elseif($param == 2) {
            return $this->locator->get(Thing2Manager::class);
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("...");
    }
}


// ServiceLocatorInterface
interface ServiceLocatorInterface
{
    public function get(string $id);
}


// ThingLocator
class ThingLocator implements ServiceLocatorInterface, ServiceSubscriberInterface
{
    private $locator;

    public function __ construct(ContainerInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function get(string $id)
    {
        if (!$this->locator->has($id)) {
            throw new \Exception("The entry for the given '$id' identifier was not found.");
        }

        try {
            return $this->locator->get($id);
        } catch (ContainerExceptionInterface $e) {
            throw new \Exception("Failed to fetch the entry for the given '$id' identifier.");
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return [
            Thing1Manager::class,
            Thing2Manager::class,
        ];
    }
}


// ThingManagerInterface
interface ThingManagerInterface
{
    public function doSomething();
}


// Thing1Manager
class Thing1Manager implements ThingManagerInterface
{
    // ...
    private $spec1Manager;

    public function __construct($firstManager, $secondManager, $thirdManager, $spec1Manager)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // This setter is no more needed. This manager can be added to the constructor method.
    // **
    // * @required
    // */
    //public function setSpecificManager(Spec1Manager $spec1Manager)
    //{
        // if not commented, this code would be called thanks to the Service Locator (which is a Symfony Service Container)
    //    $this->spec1Manager = $spec1Manager;
    //}

    public function doSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```